# AngularJS hash causes redirect to fail

Tags: angularjs, paymill

I have build an AngularJS application and want to use paymill.com to offer different payment methods. I am currently struggling with PayPal. 
This api-call allows me to specify a redirect url where the customer gets redirected to after the payment:
https://developers.paymill.com/API/index#create-new-payment-checksum

I get a response with this URL as 'return_url':

`http%3A%2F%2Ftest.test.com%2F%23%2Fteatimes%2Fbuy%2Fp82uHoLI6z%2F1`

which seems to be the correct encoding for:

`http://test.test.com/#/teatimes/buy/p82uHoLI6z/1`

Sadly the redirect after the payment does not work and simply redirects me to:`http://test.test.com/?paypal_parameters/#/`.
So it seems like that everything after the hashtag gets ommited...Is there a way to fix this on my end? I would rather not use html5 mode.

EDIT: If i use the above url without the '#' i get correctly redirect, but angularjs is unable to resolve this of course.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don´t you wanna use the html5 mode? you wouldn´t have any issue with the hashtag.

What angular method do you use for redirecting to the URL.

Comment: Well, even though html5 is supported in many browsers there are still many users using older ones. I resorted back to using html5mode in the end since i saw no other suitable solution. Users with old browsers won't be able to use PayPal though, which kinda sucks.